# RxJs - Unsubscribe when observed value is false while expecting side effect

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have a situation in which a dialog can be opened when we receive an updated from BE via SSE but closed when another update changes the previous state.

I created a helper function which is called from within an `effect` and takes opened dialog ref as a parameter. There I subscribe to device status update and if the condition is met dialog is closed and selector should be unsubscribed. But it should also be unsubscribed when user closes the dialog manually. Now the resulting code seems very strange to me.

```
private closeOnStatusChange(dialog: MatDialogRef<ConfirmDialogComponent>): void {
  this.store
    .select(fromDevice.selectDeviceStatus)
    .pipe(
      map(({ deviceStatus }) => deviceStatus === DeviceStatus.INACTIVE || deviceStatus === DeviceStatus.FAILED),
      takeWhile(shouldClose => !shouldClose), // if status is 'ok', observe but do not unsubscribe
      takeUntil(dialog.afterClosed()),  // unsubscribe when dialog is closed
      filter(shouldClose => shouldClose), // status is 'fail', continue and close the dialog
      tap(() => dialog.close())
    )
    .subscribe();
}
```

Honestly I can't figure it out, if this chain is correct or if there are some hidden catches. After a brief testing it looks like it's working but it just feels wrong. Any idea how to handle this, possibly without using helper variables?

Answer (score 0):

Try use `take` - it takes only 1 event and unsubscribe immediately. I additionally shift your `tap` to subscribe (but you can left it after `take(1)`). Code from head - not tested

```js
.pipe(
      map(({ deviceStatus }) => deviceStatus === DeviceStatus.INACTIVE || deviceStatus === DeviceStatus.FAILED),
      takeWhile(shouldClose => !shouldClose), // if status is 'ok', observe but do not unsubscribe
      takeUntil(dialog.afterClosed()),  // unsubscribe when dialog is closed
      filter(shouldClose => shouldClose), // status is 'fail', continue and close the dialog
      take(1)
      )
.subscribe(() => dialog.close())
```

Comment: If it's used after `filter` does that mean I can avoid `takeWhile`. I'm never sure about this

Comment: @dallows I not clearly understand you (main) question, but you ask about unsubscription after thing are done - so I give answer to this part of your question. However if you have two sources of events - may be it will be better to describe it in explicite way as two separate observables, filter them- and merge using e.g. `merge` and then  `take`...